# Server not sending array to hbs view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a GET route listening as follows:

```
app.get(("/employee/:id"), (req, res) => {
    data.getEmployeeByNum(req.params.id).then((data) => {
        res.render("employee", {employee: data});
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        res.render("employee", {message:"no results"});
    });
});
```

And my `employee.hbs` view awaits from the server as follows,

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}} - Employee: {{employee.employeeNum}}</h2>
    <hr />
    <form method="post" action="/employee/update">
        <fieldset>
           ...                     ...                   ...
```

I've added `console.log(data)` to ascertain and verify that the correct data from appropriate employee gets rendered. Ie the path `/employee/5` correctly returns,

```
[ { employeeNum: 5,
    firstName: 'Ysabel',
    lastName: 'Collyns',
    email: 'ycollyns4@myCompany.com',
    SSN: '930-71-9325',
    addressStreet: '529 Grim Lane',
    addresCity: 'New York',
    addressState: 'NY',
    addressPostal: '62205',
    maritalStatus: 'married',
    isManager: true,
    employeeManagerNum: null,
    status: 'Full Time',
    department: 6,
    hireDate: '4/18/2011' } ]
```

Any thoughts? Not sure what Im missing here. Instead of returning

`<h2>Ysabel Collyns - Employee: 5</h2>`

It returns

`<h2> - Employee: </h2>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<h2>{{employee.0.firstName}} {{employee.0.lastName}} - Employee: {{employee.0.employeeNum}}</h2>`, as the object is in an array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in one of my module functions,

The correct version:

```
module.exports.getEmployeeByNum = function(num) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var temp = [];
        let j = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i].employeeNum == num) {
                temp[j] = employees[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (temp.length == 0) {
            reject("No results");
        } else {
            resolve(temp[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

The issue was that I was calling `resolve(temp);` instead of `resolve(temp[0]);`